# How to write XPATH in nested elements of siblings

Tags: xpath

I have such DOM structure:

```
<td>
  <a href="/2"><div class="name">Max</div></a>
</td>
<td>Sales Officer</td>
<td>mail@mail.com</td>
<td class="links">
  <a class="edit" href="/edit"><i class="second"></i>Edit Profile</a>
</td>
```

The main goal is to click on Edit button for particular user. And I have different users (they are in another rows of table).
I need to get xpath which contains the combination of name `Max` and text `Edit Profile`.

The main problem for me that both elements are in sibling `td` tags.
I've never written anything similar before.
`//a[text()='Max']`   `//i[text()='Edit Profile']`
What should I add between this to xpathes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
//td[a="Max"]/following-sibling::td/a[.="Edit Profile"]
```

Comment: Welcome. You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Comment: And how should we change `//td[a="Max"]`       If first part will change on:  `<a> <div>Max</div> <span> text</span> </a>`

Comment: `//td[a="Maxtext"]` or `//td[a[div="Max"]]` or `//td[.//div="Max"]`, etc...